Change item in Apache configuration file with `awk`
I am not an expert with awk tool. I must miss something obvious...
What works so far:
[root@checkmk ~]# awk '/^[[:blank:]]*SSLCertificateFile/ {gsub(/\/etc\//, "/not_etc/")} 1' \
 /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf.tmp \
 | grep SSLCertificateFile
#   Point SSLCertificateFile at a PEM encoded certificate.  If
  SSLCertificateFile /not_etc/pki/tls/certs/localhost.crt
#   the referenced file can be the same as SSLCertificateFile

This works as intended.
But when i try:
[root@checkmk ~]# awk '/^[[:blank:]]*SSLCertificateFile/ {gsub(/.*\n/, "/etc/pki/public/viridian.city.pem")} 1' \
 /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf.tmp \
 | grep SSLCertificateFile
#   Point SSLCertificateFile at a PEM encoded certificate.  If
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/localhost.crt
#   the referenced file can be the same as SSLCertificateFile

It does not sub. anything... I tried different expressions like /.*\n/,/.*\n$/, /.+\n/, etc... with no success.
If i try the following, it works, but I won't maintain the indentation, if any.
awk '/^[[:blank:]]*SSLCertificateFile/ {gsub(/.*/, "SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/public/viridian.city.pem")} 1' \
 /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf.tmp \
 | grep SSLCertificateFile

I didn't though /.* would match whole line, instead of only  /etc/pki/tls/certs/localhost.crt. How would you do to only substitute the value?
Of course, I want to substitute the entire path with another one (whole line alternative works but it is not the best solution).
Would sed be a more straightforward approach here?

awk reads it's input 1 newline-separated record at a time by default. Your regexp in gsub(/.*\n/,...) is trying to match a newline (\n) in the current input record but there can't be a newline in a record when records are separated by newlines. Maybe you meant to use $ (the end-of-string regexp metachar which matches at the end of the line if the record is a single line, as it is by default) instead of \n (the line-feed escape sequence) in your regexp, I don't know, but if you did then there are better ways to do that with awk. You'd have this same problem and more with sed.
You didn't provide any sample input and expected output for us to test with so it's hard to help you any further than that.
